# Remove few characters from a string after \\ in java

Tags: java, string

I want to remove only 5 characters from a string after the occurrence of "\"(double back slash).
For example:-

```
String s = ":zap:\\ufe0f:umbrella:\\ufe0f:snowflake:\\ufe0f:snowman:\\ufe0f:cyclone:" ;
```

The output should be :

```
:zap::umbrella::snowflake::snowman::cyclone:
```

So, in the above string the 5 letters after the \ (double back slash) has been removed. 
How can I achieve this ?

I tried some code but no luck. :(

Comment: would be nice to see your implementation

Comment: You know what `\uXXXX` means right?

Comment: it's an unicode which represents a single char.

Comment: yes, but I want to just remove it from the string.

Comment: s.replace("\ufe0f", "")?

Comment: Why not try with `s.replaceAll("\ufe0f", "")` ?

Comment: I cannot try that because I can also get some different unicode like \ud83d.

Comment: then s.replaceAll("\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}", "");

Comment: Your question is not very well defined. Right now it looks to me like "there are some characters in my strings that I want to remove". You need to specify more clearly which characters you want to keep and which you want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ufe0f` is an unicode which represents a single character.

This code will remove any character but not of a word character or colon.

```
String s = ":zap:\ufe0f:umbrella:\ufe0f:snowflake:\ufe0f:snowman:\ufe0f:cyclone:" ;
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^\\w:]", ""));
```

Output:

```
:zap::umbrella::snowflake::snowman::cyclone:
```

Comment: use `string.replaceAll` function. Not `replace`

Comment: Ok then, I see it now, the problem was the use of replace() instead of replaceAll()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Regex  `"/\\.{5}/g"` with the replaceAll() method:

```
String s = ":zap:\ufe0f:umbrella:\ufe0f:snowflake:\ufe0f:snowman:\ufe0f:cyclone:" ;
s=s.replaceAll("/\\.{5}/g", "");
```

Here is a [DEMO of the Regex](https://regex101.com/r/tW8nY0/1).

> it matches any character exactly 5 times after the `\`.

It gives this output:

```
:zap:️:umbrella:️:snowflake:️:snowman:️:cyclone:
```

You can try [**The working Example here**](https://ideone.com/6EIiVk)

Comment: It doesn't work. `\ufe0f` is still in the string, it just doesn't show in the output. The string is unchanged by the regex. Here's proof: https://ideone.com/CdWSt3

Comment: I don't understand why it behaves like this! even if it matches the regex. And the others regex too?

Comment: The string doesn't have any `\ ` in it. `\ufe0f` is a single character with the hex code of FE0F, a Variation Selector.